# timeout between clicks jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following code to count clicks on a div

```
$('.ps-next').click(function () {
    setTimeout($('#currentImage').html(parseInt($('#currentImage').html(), 10) - 1), 10000);
});

$('.ps-prev').click(function () {
    setTimeout($('#currentImage').html(parseInt($('#currentImage').html(), 10) + 1), 10000);
});
```

i would like to count clicks but i want to put a delay of 1 second between clicks. or at least not count fast clicks can anyone help me.

Comment: You can disable the button when the click occurs and enable it again after 1 second

Comment: What is not working? You just have set it to 10 seconds.

Comment: ya i know but i tried to put a delay on counter but it is not working at all i can click very fast and it's counting all my clicks i want to put a delay between clicks or count 1 click per second

Comment: Your code is just creating a bunch of timeouts without clearing them. It's not going to do anything for the first 10 seconds of clicking then come in like crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a slightly different approach than most here.

The event object has a `timeStamp` property, so I compare that to the previous timestamp. Here's how I'd approach the situation...

```
var lastClick, 
    $count = $('.count');

$('.stepper').on('click', function(e){

  // If we have a lastClick value or the current timeStamp
  // minus lastClick is greater than 1000 ( 1 second ), go to work.
  if ( !lastClick || lastClick && e.timeStamp - lastClick > 1000 ) {

    var $stepper = $(this);

    $count.text(function(i, txt){
      var current = +txt;
      return current + ( $stepper.is('.up') ? 1 : -1 );
    });

    lastClick = e.timeStamp;
  }

});
```

Along with this HTML.

```
<div class="stepper up">Up</div>
<div class="count">5</div>
<div class="stepper down">Down</div>
```

Here is a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/iruXisOn/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

you can use this jquery plugin

```
(function ($) { 
    $.fn.oneClickPerTime = function (callback,timeDelay) {
        var __this = this;
        flagOneClick = 1;
        return this.each(function () {
            $(__this).click(function() {
                if (flagOneClick==0)
                    return;
                flagOneClick = 0;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    flagOneClick = 1;
                },timeDelay);
                callback(this);
            });
        });
    } 
})(jQuery);
```

then call function and must define the timeout, ex: 1000 (1 second)

```
$('.ps-prev').oneClickPerTime(function(){
     //callback
},1000);
```